# Inability to Upload File(s) in Release Mode on Firebase Storage

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-storage, testflight

I'm using flavors in my codebase together with environment variables (.env). While working on debug mode, I'm able to upload files to FirebaseStorage, but once the app is deploy on either TestFlight (for iOS) or Internal Testing (android), uploading of files files to work.

I have a singleton setup which default to the test environment/project on firebase

```
static final String firebaseCloudStorageUrl = kReleaseMode
      ? dotenv.get("APP_STORAGE_DEV")
      : dotenv.get("APP_STORAGE_DEV");
```

This is the class from where the FirebaseStorage instance is assigned.

```
final _storage =
      FirebaseStorage.instanceFor(bucket: ApiUrl.firebaseCloudStorageUrl);
```

This is the method that handles uploading file(s) to FirebaseStorage

```
  @override
  Future<List<String>> uploadImageWithCloudStorage({
    required List<File> files,
    required String userId,
  }) async {
    try {
      List<String> result = [];
      for (File file in files) {
        String fileName = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
        List<int> bytes = await file.readAsBytes();
        Uint8List data = Uint8List.fromList(bytes);
        TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await _storage
            .ref()
            .child("/$userId")
            .child(fileName)
            .putData(data);

        String url = (await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL());
        result.add(url);
      }

      if (result.isNotEmpty) {
        return result;
      }

      throw Failure("Couldn't upload files");
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      throw Failure("No internet connection");
    } on HttpException {
      throw Failure("Service currently unavailable");
    } on Failure catch (e) {
      throw Failure(e.message);
    } catch (e) {
      throw Failure("Something went wrong. Try again");
    }
  }
```

This are the methods I use to generate ".ipa" and ".aab" for iOS and android respectively

```
flutter build ipa --flavor development --target lib/main_development.dart
```

```
flutter build appbundle -t lib/main_development.dart –flavor development
```

NOTE: I also have my "firebase_options" file for both flavors set up and the respective "GoogleService-Info" copied into the appropriate directories.

I've tried updating firebase based packages on the project to see if the issue could be from there

Comment: Are you facing issue only on uploading file and other firebase features or APIs working?

Comment: I'm only facing issues uploading files. Other firebase features work.

Comment: This error is irrelevant and came from an entirely different part of the codebase.

Comment: Did you found any solution, I am also facing same issue, only with release mode while uploading images, rest everything works well

Comment: I've resolved the issue. Didn't have anything to do with Firebase. Maybe share your issue if it's different.